# Codeigniter route with condition from parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have some problem with route.i want to send different url from one fuction.here sample

this is my fuction

```
    function road($1,$2,$3){
bla bla bla
}
```

and
 i want route

```
localhost/index.php/mycontroller/road/1/2/3
```

to

```
localhost/index.php/mycontroller/road/1/2/3
```

and if $3 =0.i want to route it to

```
localhost/index.php/mycontroller/street/1/2/0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a [redirect](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#redirect) in your function `road()`

```
if($3 === 0)
    redirect('mycontroller/street/'$1 . '/' . $2 . '/' . $3);
```

Or set a custom route in `config/routes.php`

```
$route['mycontroller/road/(:any)/(:any)/0'] = 'mycontroller/street/$1/$2/0';
```

Edit :
The `redirect()` function is available once you have load the `url_helper`. You can do it in `config/autoload.php` or by adding this line before calling the function : `$this->load->helper('url');`